# Set minimum time for ajax call to return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, css-animations

On click of a button, I am running an ajax request. I am also changing the body class to perform a css animation (that makes room for the ajax data) and takes approximately 1.5 seconds. I do not want the ajax to return data before this time.

My ajax request looks like this:

```
function ajax(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: API.hostname + url,
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function() {
            $html.css("cursor", "default");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Ideally, I run a timer, and check to see if it has been a full 1.5 seconds, and if so, then run the callback. Any thoughts on what to do here? I basically want to avoid the situation where data loads before the animation has completed.

Comment: set timeout for 1.5s after ajax sucess event

Comment: @JCHASE11 did you get this worked out?

Answer (score 2):

So here is the deal. You are going to kick off the animation at the same time as you kick off the ajax, and not fire the callback until the animation is complete. So...

```
|--------------------------------|
animation starts                 animation completes
|---------------|----------------|
ajax starts     ajax completes   callback fires
```

or

```
|--------------------------------|
animation starts                 animation completes
|------------------------------------------|
ajax starts                                ajax completes / callback fires
```

so if the ajax comes back before the animation is done, it waits for the animation, and if the ajax comes after the animation, it will fire right away. This is the best of both worlds to a degree, because animation is always respected, and the user will not have to wait for lazy ajax request (one occurring after the animation).

```
function ajax(url) {
    // init cb to null
    var cb = null;
    // start the 1.5 second long animation
    animationStart();
    // set timeout for 1.5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        // cb will be set to a function if the ajax has completed already
        if(cb){
            // ajax has already completed
            cb(); // run the function set by ajax success
        }else{
            // ajax has not yet completed
            cb = true; // set value to true
        }        
    }, 1500);
    // start the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: API.hostname + url,
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function() {
            $html.css("cursor", "default");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // the cb will be set by the timeout if the animation is complete already
            if(cb){
                // animation was already complete, fire the callback right away
                callback(response);    
            }else{
                // animation is not yet complete, set cb to a function, so the callback can
                // run it when the animation is complete
                cb = function(){ callback(response);   };
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution by me:

```
function startanim(){
    //here is the script for starting the animation
}
function stopanim(){
    //here is the script for stopping the animation
}
function ajax(url) {

    startanim();//start your animation before the ajax call
    //set a timeout if you want to set the minimum time for animation
    setTimeout(function (){
        $.ajax({
            url: API.hostname + url,
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function() {
                $html.css("cursor", "default");
            },
            success: function (response) {

                callback(response);
            },
            error   : function (a){
                alert(a.responseText); //trap the cause of error
            }
        }).done(function (){
            stopanim();//stop your animation after the ajax done 
        });

    },"1400",url);
    //timeout is 1400ms. Let's say that the ajax needs 100ms to complete, so it will be 1500ms.
}
```

Comment: This is not ideal. You are making the user wait the maximum amount of time to address the animation.

Comment: The question was not clear. Now the question is updated, so (may be) you don't know how the questions was (before it updated).

Comment: For the updated question, just replace `setTimeout` from my answer. it would be what @Tommyixi wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write an ajax done method that will only fire once the request has been made.

Official documentation from the jQuery site: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

```
function ajax(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: API.hostname + url,
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function() {
            $html.css("cursor", "default");
        }.done(function(event){
        do something cool
        }),
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This doesnt work for me. I need to ensure that callback(response) is what returns after at least 1.5 seconds from the request

Comment: I see. In that case you could use .delay()

Comment: @JCHASE11 are you sure that your ajax will always done in 1.5s? I think you should start your animation before the ajax call and then end your animation after the ajax done.

Comment: nope, the animation is done in 1.5 The ajax request can take anywhere from 200ms to 4 seconds. I want to ensure that it doesnt become visible before 1.5 seconds.